# Import fonts in NextJS

Tags: fonts, next.js

I'm trying to import fonts in my project and I'm getting error:

```
./src/static/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

fonts-loader.ts file:

```
import MontserratBold from '@static/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'
import MontserratItalic from '@static/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Italic.ttf'
import MontserratLight from '@static/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Light.ttf'
import MontserratRegular from '@static/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'

export default {
  MontserratLight,
  MontserratRegular,
  MontserratItalic,
  MontserratBold,
}
```